# How to display customised banners in Product category landing pages

Tags: magento-1.9

I wish to create my own banners for the category pages . How to dispaly them ?

Comment: do you want to display single banner or do you want to display multiple images slideshow in category landing page ?

Comment: I wish to display single banner for a particular category landing page but different banners for different categry landing pges

Comment: than you can upload images under Catalog > Manage Categories in backend as i suggested in answer. let me know if you face any problems

Comment: Hi. Please check the url https://www.globalbathrooms.co.uk/heating.html

Comment: It shows  Heating
Home Heating

Comment: did you uploaded the category image from backend ?

Comment: We wish to replace this with some customised banner

Comment: you can upload banner in Catalog > Manage Categories and if you click on any category , you can see `image` option. did you uploaded image and save the category ?

Comment: Yes. I did this. Bu the image shows up below this Grey Banner which has the landing page link. I wish to replace this grey background banner with a customised banner..

Comment: you can use css to display on proper place. i can not able to see the image , can you tell me near to which text it is present or giv me url like [this](https://www.globalbathrooms.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/topbanner_near_Logo.jpg)

Comment: did you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply upload category image under `Catalog > Manage Categories`